# Debugging extension code in firefox (javascript debugger/venkman)

Tags: debugging, firefox

I'm currently working on a simple extension for Firefox.  Now I would like to be able to issue some commands in a console in the extensions context.

I have installed the Javascript Debugger addon (venkman) but following the instructions:

- uncheck "Exclude Application Files"
- choose file and right-click "Set as Evaluation Object"

never sets the context, I always end up (or rather stay) in the venkman.xul context.

I would switch to another debugger, but so far had no luck with chromebug either:

- installed chromebug 1.08a2 and matching firebug
- started firefox with -chromebug -P dev (as a seperate 'firefox' for development)

then chromebug on its own window doesn't let me choose a context, in fact it doesn't even show ANY context, all panels are deactivated.

I really don't have any idea where to look any more and would love to have a solution.
For now I don't even need all the 'fancy' debugger stuff like setting breakpoints, just need to issue commands at chrome level.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firefox now has a built-in debugger that easy rivals, and perhaps surpasses firebug, chromebug or venkman.

[You need to enable (or create) 2 particular options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript#JavaScript_Debugger_.28Venkman.29) in `about:config` for extension debugging to work:

```
devtools.chrome.enabled: true
devtools.debugger.remote-enabled: true
```

And then click the new "Browser Debugger" entry in the Web Developer menu. The "Browser Console" is also very useful.

The [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript#JavaScript_Debugger_.28Venkman.29) mentions that this will work from Firefox 19, but actually it will [only work well on all extension code from Firefox 23 onwards](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?p=28311&sid=918643229cb8ab39e244441a17493534). (If you try this before Firefox 22 is released, just install [the latest nightly build](http://nightly.mozilla.org/).)

Also note that if you're [editing extension code directly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file) you will need get Firefox to refresh e.g. by using the reload all chrome extension using [the tips mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1079453/125150) before the debugger will list the updated code.

**Update:** Firefox v32 and later has built-in debugging support for **[restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) and [SDK-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) add-ons**. As [stated in Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Debugger), the "remote debug" mentioned above now has a checkbox in the Web Developer pane's settings:

[image]

You can then go to the add-ons -> extensions tab and click "debug" alongside the name of you extension.